# Why is toolbox of ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap not in ArcToolbox?

Tags: openstreetmap, arctoolbox, arcgis-editor-osm

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0 and I tried to install [ArcGIS Editor for OSM](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/) (version 2.0) on ArcGIS

But I couldn't make my ArcToolbox list the tools that **ArcGIS Editor for OSM should've installed**.

Any ideas about that?

[image: OpenStreetMap tools doesn't appear in ArcToolbox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the [ArcGIS Editor for OSM documentation](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Download%20Data%20from%20OSM&referringTitle=Documentation):

"4.In the ArcCatalog window, browse to the directory where you installed ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap (e.g., C:\Program Files\ESRI\OSMEditor) and the data folder. Doubleclick on the Download, Extract, and Symbolize OSM Data model. "

For some reason they chose to leave it there rather than placing its toolbox in ArcToolbox.  To make it appear and remain in ArcToolbox at 10.0 use **Add Toolbox**, browse to find it, and then **Save Settings > To Default**.

Answer (score 2):

With version 10.2 for ArcGIS on windows 8.1, I was not able to add the toolbox.  This is because the installer did not copy the 'data' folder.

To get the data folder, I had to download the source code from github, and place it into the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\OSMEditor